# Need MYSQL query to insert value in different columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using Php to insert values into MySQL table.

What i am trying to do is:
There are three columns that i have to check. 'namel1', 'namel2' and 'namel3'.

Conditions:

- If '$name' does't exist in any of the three column then put value in 'namel1'.
- If '$name' exist in 'namel1' then put value in 'namel2' and if 'namel2' contains the value then put it in 'namel3'.

My current MySQL query to insert name and image path is this i want to modify it to meet above conditions:

```
$chk_img_db = mysql_query("select * from cvapptable where img_path='$cvh_myimg_url'");
if(mysql_num_rows($chk_img_db)<1) {
mysql_query("insert into cvapptable(namel1,img_path) values ('$name','$cvh_myimg_url')");
}
```

I unable to get any solution from web.
Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean put the value in namel3 of a name exists in namel2?

Comment: ohh sorry its name l3 - fixed. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not easy to find on the net because it's a situation you shouldn't get yourself into.

You should consider normalizing the table.

Instead of having a table with the columns:

```
cvapp: id | img_path | namel1 | namel2 | namel3
```

Consider changing it to two tables:

```
cvapp: id | img_path
names: id | cvapp_id   | name
```

To then select every name, you just do a query like so:

```
SELECT name
  FROM cvapp INNER JOIN names on cvapp.id = names.cvapp_id
 WHERE <condition>
```

That way, you can have as many names as you want, and it's much easier to insert a new one:

```
INSERT INTO names (cvapp_id, name) VALUES (56, "Name 1");
INSERT INTO names (cvapp_id, name) VALUES (56, "Name 2");
INSERT INTO names (cvapp_id, name) VALUES (56, "Name 3");
```

Comment: but what happen when i want select an image and want to get its different names how that could possible.

Comment: @AashuAbhee: I gave you that very example in the answer. :)

Comment: can you post an answer without join because there are other things also that i didn't explain. and this change a lot to my script. so please can you give one more answer without join using one table only here.http://stackoverflow.com/q/11901798/1076003

Comment: @AashuAbhee: Take it as an opportunity to improve your database design. :)

Comment: let me provide more in deep detail than give me this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try self join and search column of you tables